# Universal Home button method

Tags: android, android-activity

I know, similar topic was raised thousand times, I rode some of them, however.

I got main activity A. I got couple of other activities, lets say: B, C, D. On B, C, D i got this button with goHome() method.

I'd like to write this method once and then use it on activity B,C,D. I don't want to create method all over again on each activity class. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the child activities (here B,C,D) extend a class that handles `onActivityResult()`. When starting their intent, use `startActivityForResult()`, and pass a request and response code.

When those codes are received by `onActivityResult()`, simply have it `finish()`. This will automatically bring the user from any child activity back to activity A.

Comment: @Xylian Object oriented design facilitates solutions to many of these problems.. I would recommend researching object oriented techniques as they will make you a much more efficient and organized coder, regardless if you are a lone wolf or a team member.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class which contains static methods only.
You didn't say if you go from  B,C,D back to A by pressing the back button or by starting a new Activity.
However, put this static method in the onBackPressed method or in you "goHome()" method.

```
class StaticCode{

  static void goHome(){
  // the things generally done in B.goHome(), C.goHome(), D.goHome();
  }

}
```

Then call it evenly in B, C, D:

```
class B extends Activity{
   ...  

 public void goHome(){
  StaticCode.goHome();
 }

}
```

Note to pass parameters to the static method as required, for instance the Context.

Comment: Why not `StaticCode.goHome()` directly?

Comment: @Floern You can call this method whatever you like :)